# Core dumped in C program

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, coredump

I fairly old to C programming (even though I haven't programmed in C for many years) but I am utterly stuck now. I have two source files:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "inputFunction.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *invoiceFile=NULL, *inputFile=NULL, *configFile=NULL;
    getInput(argc, argv, &invoiceFile, &inputFile, &configFile);
    if(invoiceFile!=NULL){
        free(invoiceFile);
    }
    if(inputFile!=NULL){
        free(inputFile);
    }
    if(configFile!=NULL){
        free(configFile);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

and inputFunction.c

```
#include "inputFunction.h"

int getInput(int argc, char** argv, char **invoiceFile, char **inputFile, char **configFile) {
    int i;
    if (argc != 3 && argc != 5 && argc != 7) {
        inputError();
        return 1;
    } else {
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i += 2) {
            if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-o")) {
                if (*invoiceFile == NULL) {
                    if (((*invoiceFile) = malloc((strnlen(argv[i + 1], 256) + 1) * sizeof (char))) == NULL) {
                        perror("A problem occurred when allocating memory.\n");
                        return 1;
                    }
                    strncpy((*invoiceFile), argv[i + 1], 256);
                } else {
                    inputError();
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-i")) {
                if (*inputFile == NULL) {
                    if (((*inputFile) = malloc((strnlen(argv[i + 1], 256) + 1) * sizeof (char))) == NULL) {
                        perror("A problem occurred when allocating memory.\n");
                        return 1;
                    }
                    strncpy((*inputFile), argv[i + 1], 256);
                } else {
                    inputError();
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-c")) {
                if (*configFile == NULL) {
                    if (((*configFile) = malloc((strnlen(argv[i + 1], 256) + 1) * sizeof (char))) == NULL) {
                        perror("A problem occurred when allocating memory.\n");
                        return 1;
                    }
                    strncpy((*configFile), argv[i + 1], 256);
                } else {
                    inputError();
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (*invoiceFile == NULL) {
        inputError();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void inputError() {
    printf("\nInvalid input\n");
    printf("Correct input parameters are:\n");
    printf("-o InvoiceFile\n");
    printf("-i InputFile (optional)\n");
    printf("-c configFile (optional)\n\n\n");
}
```

and a header file:

inputFunction.h

```
#ifndef INPUTFUNCTION_H
#define INPUTFUNCTION_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int getInput(int argc, char** argv, char **invoiceFile, char **inputFile, char **configFile);

void inputError();

#endif  /* INPUTFUNCTION_H */
```

The program gets 3 parameters from the command line with a filename after each one (only one is obligatory the "-o" along with its filename). So when I put all (total 6) of them and run the program, it crashes giving me:

```
Project1: malloc.c:2369: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

RUN FINISHED; Aborted; core dumped; real time: 120ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

So I used valgrind which gave me this output:

```
    ==8082== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8082== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8082== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8082== Command: ./out -i ab -c bc -o cd
==8082== 
==8082== Invalid write of size 1
==8082==    at 0x4C2DAEC: strncpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8082==    by 0x400971: getInput (inputFunction.c:33)
==8082==    by 0x400730: main (main.c:11)
==8082==  Address 0x51fc043 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==8082==    at 0x4C2A2DB: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8082==    by 0x400915: getInput (inputFunction.c:29)
==8082==    by 0x400730: main (main.c:11)
==8082== 

valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:268 (mk_plain_bszB): Assertion 'bszB != 0' failed.
valgrind: This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.

==8082==    at 0x380581EF: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8082==    by 0x38058332: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8082==    by 0x3806257A: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8082==    by 0x380641F3: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8082==    by 0x3802B33C: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8082==    by 0x3802B4C2: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8082==    by 0x3809D58D: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8082==    by 0x380AC14C: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable
==8082==    at 0x4C2A2DB: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8082==    by 0x4009F7: getInput (inputFunction.c:41)
==8082==    by 0x400730: main (main.c:11)
```

I know that the problem is in the malloc but I can not find it. Any help?
I am using Netbeans 7.4 on Lubuntu 13.10 with gcc 4.8.1.

Comment: Read man page of *strncpy* carefully, it does not do what you'd think. Use *strncat* or *snprintf* instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some more research I saw [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/strncpy.html) that the strncpy copies n characters even if the source string is smaller than n characters. That way it was getting out of bounds of the destination string's allocated memory.

Answer (score 7):

Part of the problem may be due to the use of `strnlen` and `strncpy`.  If the length of the input string given to `strnlen` is less than 256, it will return the actual length (a value less than 256).  So the result is that `malloc` would allocate that many bytes.  But the call to `strncpy` indicates the buffer is 256 bytes.  And `strncpy` always pads up to the given length, so it is likely resulting in a memory overwrite.

Unless there is a specific reason for using strnlen, it might be simpler to use [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup), which will allocate and copy with a single call.

Comment: Thanks mate. I just realized it myself... :(

Comment: Note, *strdup* is not standard C (it is standard POSIX etc, though).